# Question on "Proving $f(x) = 0$ everywhere"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I've some questions on Brian M Scott's proof for [Proving $f(x) = 0$ everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115826/proving-fx-0-everywhere). Please do combine my thread with the original which might be easier to read. Thank you.

> Let $f:[0,1] \to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. 
>   Suppose that for all $x \in (0,1)$, there exists a $0 < d < \min\{x,1-x\}$ such that: $f(x) = \frac12\Big(f(x-d) + f(x+d)\Big)\;. $ $^{\huge{1}}$
>   $ \text{Prove that } f(x)=0 \text{ everywhere} $.

My version of Brian M Scott's Proof (by Contradiction) $^{\huge{2}}$:

> Suppose that $f$ is not identically $0$. 
>   Then $f$ attains a non-zero extremum at some point $c\in(0,1).$ 
>   Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=f(c)\}$. 
>   }
>   Since $f$ is continuous, $A$ is closed and has a least element $a$. $^{\huge{3}}$ $^{\huge{4}}$ By definition of $A$ , $a \in (0,1]$.
>   Then there exists $0 < d<\min\{a,1-a\}$ such that $f(a)=\frac12\Big(f(a-d)+f(a+d)\Big).$
>
> But since $f$ attains its maximum at $a$, $f(a)=f(a-d)$ $^{\huge{5}}$, which is impossible.

Question 1: How can I understand this complicated definition of $f(x)$ intuitively? This might help me with better understanding this problem.

Question 2: Is there a direct way to show this? Why choose to prove by contradiction?

Question 3: I don't understand why we need $A$ to be closed?

Question 4: On top of Question 3, wouldn't Extreme Value Theorem here be enough? I'd just say: "Since $f$ is continuous, then by Extreme Value Theorem, $A$ has a least element $a$."

Question 5: $max f(x) = f(a)$ means $ f(a) \geq f(x) $ for all $ x \in domf$. How does this imply $f(a) = f(a - d)$?

Comment: Question 2 is a good one i don't see a direct proof for this one, did a left another question open ?

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by "did a left another question open?" Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Thank you very much Dominic Michaelis! Yes, of course! I stepped away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh how to descripe the function the best, the function has the property, that it is the mean of two symmetric positioned values.
$A$ is closed because it is a preimage of a continuous function,
The extrem value theorem only works for compact sets.
Well since the Definition of your function you know 
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2} (f(a-d)+f(a+d)) $$ 
because of $f(a-d)\leq f(a)$ and $f(a+d)\leq f(a)$ it follows $f(a-d)=f(a+d)=f(a)$

Comment: Thank you. Some follow-ups:
$\Large{\text{Question 1}}$ : What does “Mh mean”? $\Large{\text{Question 3}}$: Are you using this result: “f is continuous iff if the inverse image of every closed set is a closed set”? Is there something easier? 
$\Large{\text{Question 4}}$: Isn’t A closed and bounded? $A := {x \in [0,1] : … }$
$\Large{\text{Question 5}}$: Sorry, still don’t see this. How does $$ A \leq C \text{ and } B \leq C  \text{ and } C = \frac{1}{2}(A + B) $$ imply $ A = B = C$?

Comment: Mh means i am not sure if there isn't a better explanation, to question 3 yes that is exactly what i am using, to question for $A$ is bounded but not necessary bounded, taking for example the function $$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl} \sin\left( \frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0 \\ 1 & x=0\\ \end{array} \right. $$ the set $A$ would be not open nor closed. ok Taking $$C=\frac{1}{2} (A+B)$$ we know $$C\leq \max\{A,B\}.$$ But we even know $$C\geq \max\{A,B\}$$, so $$C=\max\{A,B\}$$. But since $A=B$ we know $A=B=C$

Comment: @Dominic.Michaelis: Thank you very much. $\Large{\text{Question 3}}$: Do you mean $A$ is bounded in this question, but $A$ doesn't have to be bounded in general? I'm just a bit confused since you wrote "$A$" is bounded but not necessarily bounded"? $\Large{\text{Question 5}}$: How do we know $A = B$?

Comment: oh my brain trolled me :D i mean $A$ is always bounded, but in general it doesn't need to be closed (can't correct the comment anymore). It is closed cause $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Dominic.Michaelis: Great! Thanks. My last follow-up is: $\large{\text{Question 5:}}$ How do we know $f(a - d) = f(a + d$? The function $f(x)$ doesn't have to be symmetric about $x = a$?

Comment: Oh sry, we know $C\geq \max\{A,B\}$ and we know $$C=\frac{1}{2} (A+B).$$  Now suppose $A\neq B$, wlog let's say $A>B$ than there is a $x$ so that $A-x=B$. Than $$C=\frac{1}{2} (A+A-x)=A-\frac{x}{2}$$, but because $C\geq A$ this can't be true

Comment: Thank you very much again. You proved $A = B$ by contradiction, which I understand. But what's the intuition for $A = B$? How did you suspect this to be true? Surely, you must've suspected it proving it?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(A+B)$ is the mean of $A$ and $B$ so you expect $C$ to be in between $A$ and $B$. It's a bit intuition from the function, which give means of symmetric positioned values, so if the symmetric values aren't equal the function would be growing or falling, and you wouldn'T have a maximum or minimum.